# Dependiendo del valor que se genere de manera aleatoria, se le asignará un color al progress bar

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que asignarle un color a cada barra dependiendo del porcentaje que tenga, pero no se donde ni como hacer la validación, si me ayudarán se los agradeceria

este seria mi codigo en mi index.blade.php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container-sm">
<h2>Problema 5</h2>
    
    <table class="table table-white table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-sm table-responsive-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Número</th>
                <th scope="col">Valor</th>
                <th scope="col">Gráfico utilizando progress bar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($valores as $valor)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{$valor['numero']}}</th>
                <td>{{$valor["valor"]}}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="progress-bar 
                    bg-success
                    progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" style="width: {{$valor['valor']}}%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{$valor["valor"]}}%</div>

                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es la vista desde el controlador

```
public function problema5()
{
    //
    
    for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
        $valores[] = ["numero"=>$i,"valor"=>rand(1,100)];

    return view('index',['valores'=>$valores]);

 
}
```

Intente hacer las validaciones desde desde la vista, utilizando {{$valor['valor'] < 61 ? 'secondary' : ''}} , pero la verdad no se como utilizar esa validación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en el problema5 hacer la asignacion del color y devolvarla en el return view luego la agregas como si fuera otro valor.
debes usar las propiedades que entrega el mismo bootstrap para los tr o td

```
<td class="table-success">texto</td>
```

seria algo como

```
<td class="<?= $color">texto</td>
```

o asignarles un id propio y por javascript agregar la clase

```
let fila = document.getElementById("fila");
fila.classList.add("table-success");
<td id="fila">texto</td>
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda